# Badly stuck at Uninstalling Zoom Admin

Tags: 18.04, server, vpn

I was trying to create a VPN of my digital ocean server using zoomadmin.com but because of some limitations in zoom admin which i had found after installation.Now i want to uninstall zoom admin completely from my ubuntu 18.04 but 
[image]

as you can see in terminal i had found multiple zoom base packages in the list.
So i tried to uninstall it by executing follow command

```
sudo apt remove zoom
```

Commands throws back following error

```
E: Unable to locate package zoom
```

[That's official link which i had followed.](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204206269-Installing-or-updating-Zoom-on-Linux#h_5562a050-fe90-4372-90ca-cb3bb3e8f310)